# Bound on Powers of a Binomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, upper-lower-bounds

I'm trying to figure out an upper bound on $(x^2 + z^2)^p$ for an arbitrary integer power $p \geq 1$.  For instance, we have the well-known bound $(x+y)^2 \leq 3x^2 + 3y^2$, but I'm not sure how to extend this.

EDIT: For my purposes, it is sufficient to assume that $x,z \geq 0$.

Comment: My thought, and I checked with a colleague, is that I can think of this like $(a+b)^p$ with $a,b \geq 0$.  Then, we have
$(a+b)^p \leq (2^{p}-1)(a^p+b^p)$
by considering the binomial theorem expansion and adding the bounds in the two cases $a>b$ and $b>a$.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple trick to get the bound you want. Suppose $0\leq a\leq b$,
then
$$
(a+b)^p\leq (2b)^p=2^pb^p\leq 2^p(a^p+b^p).
$$
By simmetry we get the same inequality for  $0\leq b\leq a$. So in any case we have $$(a+b)^p\leq 2^p(a^p+b^p).$$

Note that $p$ can be any nonnegative real number.

Comment: Add them up and divide by 2 and you get $2^{p-1}$ as in the other answers.

Comment: @martycohen it is tempting to do it, but, as far as i can see, we can only add them up to yield the constant $2^{p-1}$ when $a=b$, because they occur in different domains.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest proof was given by Alan. Let me give a slightly different one. Note that $f(x)=x^p$ is a convex function on the positive reals. Thus we get
$$(x+y)^p= 2^p(x/2+y/2)^p=2^p f(x/2+ y/2)\leq 2^{p-1}(f(x)+f(y))= 2^{p-1}(x^p+y^p).$$
Note that this estimate is sharp (pick $x=y$). However, it only works for $p\geq 1$.